# Can we realtime update credential for pivotal cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

Can we realtime update the PCF credential for Spring Cloud DataFlow?
The credential is defined in the yaml file:
`SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_PASSWORD: xxx`

It will be very helpful when rotating the password without restarting the Spring Cloud DataFlow.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Many of our PCF customers either rely on config-server, Vault or CredHub to automatically resolve the value for user/pass or other sensitive credentials.

For instance, if you're using CredHub (service-bound to SCDF), you would have the value for this property something like:

> SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_PASSWORD: ${vcap.services.YOUR_scdf-server_credhub-sb.credentials.YOUR_scdf_cloudfoundry_password}

With this type of setting, you can rolling-update the sensitive credentials. Also, when using config-server or vault, you can remotely update the credentials in the Git backing repo, and the latest would take into account at runtime.

Comment: I'm not using config-server but I have a custom code to pull the latest credential. How can I override the method in Spring Cloud Dataflow or PCF service to supply the latest credential?